# Display additional information on the incoming call screen

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts, caller-id

I have a HTC wildfire running cyanogenmod and I really want to display the Organization for contacts along side their name and picture on the incoming-call screen.

Does anyone know of any settings/hacks/mods which can accomplish this?

Comment: When you [searched the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=caller+id&c=apps), why won't any of the apps you found do the trick?

Comment: I'd rather avoid using a custom dialler if I can.

Comment: Hack and recompile CM for your device is the short answer based on your previous comment, in avoiding using a custom dialler!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this without a custom dialler unless you make a custom Cyanogenmod version - and modify the dialler to show this information.